# SOLVED upgrade error: illegal package name `systemd/noawait'

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, systemd-resolved

when I run this `sudo apt upgrade` command I get this:

```
Reading package list ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
Calculating the update ... Done
The following packages will be updated:
  linux-libc-dev

1 updates, 0 new ones will be installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to update.

39 not fully installed or removed.
0 B / 1,141 kB of files need to be downloaded.
12.3 kB of additional disco space will be used after this operation.
do you wish to continue? [Y / n] yes

dpkg: error: trigger log file mentions a package name
Illegal you `systemd / noawait '(in the file` / usr / lib / systemd / catalog'): name
Illegal packet in value 'systemd / noawait': character `/ 'is not allowed
gone (only letters, digits characters `- + ._ 'are allowed)
E: The / usr / bin / dpkg thread returned an error code (2)
```

And i can't upgrade :((

Please help. i use ubuntu 20.04

Comment: first aid `wget -c http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb` and try to install it with dpkg `sudo dpkg -i systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb`  `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: So, i run the command ```sudo dpkg -i systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.6_amd64.deb``` and show this ```dpkg: error: the trigger logs file mentions an illegal package name `systemd / noawait '(in the file` / usr / lib / systemd / catalog'): illegal package name in the value 'systemd / noawait': the character `/ 'is not allowed (only letters, digits characters` - + ._' are allowed)```

Comment: Okay `file /usr/lib/systemd/catalog`  please.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# ```file /usr/lib/systemd/catalog```    (i run the command and show this)   ```/usr/lib/systemd/catalog: directory```

Comment: I do this. I run this ```sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File``` and i delete this ```/usr/lib/ systemd/catalog system/noawait``` and i run ```sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade``` and show this   ```dpkg: error: syntactic error in trigger file /var/lib/dpkg/trigg
ers / File '```

Comment: @LinkMales Would you share your current contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File` file?

Comment: /usr/lib/mime/packages mime-support/noawait
/usr/share/applications mime-support/noawait
/etc/dbus-1/system.d dbus/noawait
/usr/share/dbus-1/system.d dbus/noawait
/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services dbus/noawait
/etc/rsyslog.d rsyslog/noawait

Comment: Is a long list, i don't know how i can send it

Comment: I fixed the syntax error, it was just an empty space, when removing the space now I have this error ```dpkg: error: duplicate file trigger interest for file `/ usr / li
b / gtk-2.0 / 2.10.0 / immodules 'and the package `libgtk2.0-0: i386'
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (2)```

Comment: I fixed my bug, I just removed /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules libgtk2.0-0:i386/noawait and I was able to request the dpkg already, thank you very much

Comment: @LinkMales Nice. would you write an answer then set as accepted. So other may find the solution quickly. Btw, you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com if you needed another time to share long txt.

Comment: I new in askubuntu. What do i that¿?

Comment: @LinkMales See [about] for quick start. In this page, look at the bottom there is a box for "your answer". Ask Ubuntu is a Q/A site.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the document /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File, you have to look for this trigger with `sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`, then we look for /usr/lib/systemd/catalog system/noawait, then we remove it and we have already resolved the error, if an error appears like this `dpkg: error: syntactic error in trigger file /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File '`... The error is in an empty space of the document /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File.